# How can one java file call methods from another java file?

Tags: java

How do you call a method from a different class (file) in java?

Are objects required? Or is there a 3rd way to make a merge of documents for java? Can we use a simple method call of is there a proper way to call new methods?

Comment: This is a very general question, I think you need to go and read on some Java basics...

Comment: `Are objects required?` - in Java _every_ method is at least located in a _class_. To call static methods you need the class, to call instance methods you need an instance of that class.

Comment: "make a merge of documents" - What do you mean by "document"?

Comment: Java files don't exist in the running program. The files exist only to convey code to the JVM. Once in there, there's no "file" making calls, only methods. How method​ calls work is well explained in the Java Tutorial, which I strongly advise you to read.

Answer (score 18):

Your question is not clear to me, as far as I understand you want to call a method of another Java file (I assume another Java class).

So consider you have java files A.java and B.java. So you have definitely two classes A and B.

Now if you want to call a method of B class from A class you need to:

1. Make the method of B class public (or public static)
2. Create a object of B class in A (or if method is static this step is not required)
3. Using that object(in case of static user class name) call the method

Take a look:

**• Non-static method:**

**B.java**

```
class B {
   public void myMethod() {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

**A.java**

```
class A {
    public void anotherMethod()
    {
         B b=new B();
         b.myMethod();        // calling B class's method
    }
}
```

**• STATIC method:**

**B.java**

```
class B {
   public static void myMethod() {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

**A.java**

```
class A {
    public void anotherMethod()
    {
         B.myMethod();        // calling B class's method
    }
}
```

Comment: aMethod() is more like a constructor there, not a method ;-)

Comment: Ooooops... updated :p

Comment: myMethod is a better name to call the method in order not to be confused with A, I think

Comment: agreed @DirtyDev :D

Answer (score 1):

you can try packaging your class

using `package com.yourwebsite;` at the very start of your class and above import statements

then at the cmd type `javac -d . YourClass.java`

then you can import it on the next class that you are trying to create

to import it use `import com.yourwebsite.YourClass;`

note that your package doesn't allow wild card symbol so you must use the full name of your class

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked for...

Comment: Yes @Celt, but this basic steps can be useful for very begginers in Java programming.

Comment: Yes, but unrelated to the question